# How to show that a chart is a zoomed-in version of a different one?

Tags: charts, timeline, zooming

I have two side-by-side charts, showing some time series data.

What would be the best way to convey that:

- The second chart is a zoomed-in version of the first one
- Give an indication of what is the area of the first chart that's highlighted in the second one ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just draw a box on the first chart that signifies what area is highlighted in the second like so:

[image]

Alot of games use this to signify which part of the map you are seeing on your screen out of the whole map.

Or if you don't want to impede the viewing of the first chart with the overlay you can have a mini-map type view above the second  chart showing the same view.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, both my charts are too small to overlay anything on top of them. But thanks for the clues!

Comment: If the charts are so small you can't indicate the zoom area, you're going to have a very hard time making the relationship clear.

Answer (score 6):

A few additional ideas to address your zooming differentiation question:

1. Instead of an overlay, you could try a preview window with a much simpler version of the chart.

[image]

Here is an interactive
    example:  http://demos.zingchart.com/view/BWTCT87D

This gives users
    their bearings quite effectively without obscuring the chart area
    and using minimal real estate.

2. You could try letting users scroll instead of select to zoom. That way the scrollbar will show they are partway through the chart, not viewing the entire data set. Think something like this:
   [image] 
   Interactive version: http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!multiseries-bar-chart-with-scrolling

I'm on the ZingChart team, so I used their charting library to come up with these demos. Other libraries can accomplish similar features. Please let me know if I can answer any questions about the examples included here.

Comment: May be my "at-work" browser but the first demo link is not found.

Comment: Please try it again now http://demos.zingchart.com/view/BWTCT87D 
I may have not had the public settings checked properly.